How can I filter emails with an empty body in Gmail?
I use Gmail. I want to list all emails where I am the sender, there are no attachments and have an empty body.  How can I do so?

@Blindspots thanks, I can add a filter in the sender (The sender is myself ie my email address).

@Blindspots since the beginning of time

@Blindspots preferably, exclude (i.e., -has:attachment).

@Blindspots Got it, thanks very much!

I agree that this is a duplicate of the target.  Aside from them wanting to filter the Inbox and you sent folder, it is essentially the same problem.

FYI I updated the function getLabelIds() on the duplicate target to be more user-friendly allowing you to simply replace the existing constant in one step.  The updated answer
